# one Javascript Var for multiple HTML ID's. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, var

I have 1 form, for the user input, which fills out 3 forms dynamically using javascript.   on the same page

each 3 forms, have 1) a PREVIEW option, with a watermark
                   2) a PDF option without a watermark
                   3) POST variables to Paypal

There are about 25 vars..  so, 3x3x25..   that's a lot of text..  and a lot of vars.

My JS file is getting huge, and I'm running out of var names..  like..

emp_id = corp_emp_id = neat_emp_id = adv_emp_id = PDF_emp_id = PP_emp_id

From my knowledge, it seems like you can use the VAR only one time per item.  so, I have to make a different var each time?

JAVASCRIPT FILE (this is for one var of 25)

```
 var val_emp_id = document.getElementById('emp_id').value;                                                      
  document.getElementById('corp_p_emp_id3').value  =  val_emp_id;                                           
  document.getElementById('corp_emp_id3').innerHTML  =  val_emp_id;                                 
  document.getElementById('w2_p_emp_id').value  =  val_emp_id;                                          
  document.getElementById('w2_emp_id3').innerHTML  =  val_emp_id;                                   
  document.getElementById('basic_emp_id').innerHTML  =  val_emp_id;                                 
  document.getElementById('basic_p_emp_id').value  =  val_emp_id;                                           
  document.getElementById('neat_emp_id').innerHTML =  val_emp_id;
  document.getElementById('neat_p_emp_id').value  =  val_emp_id;
  document.getElementById('neat_pp_emp_id').value  =  val_emp_id;
  document.getElementById('corp_pp_emp_id').value  =  val_emp_id;
  document.getElementById('adv_pp_emp_id').value  =  val_emp_id;
```

and the HTML FILE

```
 <p id="corp_emp_id3"></p>        

 <input type="hidden" name="corp_p_emp_id" id="corp_p_emp_id3"/>

 <input type="hidden" name="corp_pp_emp_id" id="corp_p_emp_id3"/>

 <input type="hidden" name="corp_pdf_emp_id" id="corp_p_emp_id3"/>
```

Basically, my question is..  Can I use one Javascript VAR for many HTML vars?  or many Locations, without creating multiple vars for multiple elements?

Or am I stuck doing like a neanderthal?

Comment: Yes, Javascript has no problem with it.but why Would you that, your html will go invalid

Comment: I think you just need to think of a different approach. How about using an array?

Comment: so, what else you want to know ?

Comment: This is what arrays and objects are for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Javascript will allow same 'var' for all data,value will be replaced, but having same id for more than one element makes error in html.All dom elements must have unique id.You can have same class for different dom instead.[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hNprg/)`</>`

Comment: Ok, I'm fine with Using Arrays, or Classes.. But, I don't see how I would do that here? Can you give me an idea of what the code would look like?

Comment: you said "Can I use one Javascript VAR for many HTML vars", what is meaning of "html vars" here?

Comment: Sorry for my bad terminology.  HTML VARS  in my mind means input types like type=HIDDEN name=CORP_P_EMP_ID id=CORP_P_EMP_ID.    That's a var?  no?   or a "data-container"  of sorts...        and that's my problem.   I have numerous DATA-CONTAINERS 5-6 of them, holding the exact same variable.   Which seems very inefficient to me.   That is ultimately my question.

Answer (score 0):

You use a variable to store a value. But when you reinitialize it, its older value is replaced  by the newer one. In that case, to avoid multiple `vars`, you can use the `var` value before you reinitialize it. But see how to follow this approach in your code.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Ok, I'm fine with Using Arrays, or Classes..  But, I don't see how I would do that here?   Can you give me an idea of what the code would look like?